# C strtok() crashes once it reaches newline in a text file

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

The goal of this program is to take an input text file, take each word and scramble the letters between the first and last letters, then write the scrambled text to an output file. Here is the code I came up with:

```
void processFile(FILE* ifp, FILE* ofp) {
    printf("Begin file processing\n");
    char istr[MAXLINE], iword[50];
    char* token;
    char delimit[] = {" \t\r\n\v\f"};
    while(fgets(istr,MAXLINE,ifp)!= NULL) {
        token = strtok(istr,delimit);
        scramble(token);
        fputs(token,ofp);
        fputs(" ", ofp);
        while(token != NULL) {
            token = strtok(NULL,delimit);
            scramble(token);
            fputs(token,ofp);
            fputs(" ",ofp);
        }
    }
    printf("End file processing\n");
} /* processFile */

void scramble(char str[50]) {
printf("\nWord Scramble Start\n");
int len = strlen(str);
printf("strlen: %d\n",len);
int i = 0;
if(len > 3) {
    int t = str[1];
    for (int k = 1; k < len - 2; k++) str[k] = str[k + 1];
    str[len - 2] = t;
    printf("str: %s\n",str);
    }
}
```

Based on my debugging attempts, the crash seems to be happening once the program reaches a newline, even though it appears to be working just fine up until that point. This seems strange since I did include the newline character in the delimiters of strtok(). Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I'm sure if you do `char delimit[] = {" \t\r\n\v\f"}`, you only have 1 delimitor (not 6). And that single delimitor is " \t\r\n\v\f".

Comment: No, the delimiters are fine. Not checking for NULL being returned, well not so fine. You have to check for NULL after the strtok call and before you use the pointer for anything else.

Comment: Replace `while(token != NULL) {
            token = strtok(NULL,delimit);` with `while((token = strtok(NULL,delimit)) != NULL) {`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Still crashes at the same place.

Comment: With my proposed fix in place, it crashes for me on an empty line — because I didn't check the first `strtok()` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you get a non-null token from `strtok()` each time you call it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { MAXLINE = 4096 };

extern void processFile(FILE *ifp, FILE *ofp);
extern void scramble(char str[]);

void processFile(FILE *ifp, FILE *ofp)
{
    printf("Begin file processing\n");
    char istr[MAXLINE];
    char *token;
    char delimit[] = {" \t\r\n\v\f"};
    while (fgets(istr, MAXLINE, ifp) != NULL)
    {
        if ((token = strtok(istr, delimit)) != NULL)
        {
            scramble(token);
            fputs(token, ofp);
            fputs(" ", ofp);
            while ((token = strtok(NULL, delimit)) != NULL)
            {
                scramble(token);
                fputs(token, ofp);
                fputs(" ", ofp);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("End file processing\n");
}

void scramble(char str[])
{
    printf("\nWord Scramble Start\n");
    int len = strlen(str);
    printf("strlen: %d\n", len);
    if (len > 3)
    {
        int t = str[1];
        for (int k = 1; k < len - 2; k++)
            str[k] = str[k + 1];
        str[len - 2] = t;
        printf("str: %s\n", str);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    processFile(stdin, stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

Saved as `scramble97.c`.  When run as `./scramble97 < scramble97.c`, the output is:

```
Begin file processing

Word Scramble Start
strlen: 8
str: #ncludie
#ncludie 
Word Scramble Start
strlen: 9
str: <tdio.hs>
<tdio.hs> 
Word Scramble Start
strlen: 8
str: #ncludie
#ncludie 
Word Scramble Start
strlen: 10
str: <tring.hs>
<tring.hs> 
Word Scramble Start
strlen: 4
str: eunm
eunm 
Word Scramble Start
strlen: 1
{ 
Word Scramble Start
strlen: 7
str: MXLINAE
MXLINAE 
Word Scramble Start
strlen: 1
= 
Word Scramble Start
strlen: 4
str: 4906
4906 
Word Scramble Start
strlen: 2
}; 
Word Scramble Start
strlen: 6
str: eterxn
eterxn 
Word Scramble Start
strlen: 4
str: viod
viod 
Word Scramble Start

…


Word Scramble Start
strlen: 12
str: pintf("strr:
pintf("strr: 
Word Scramble Start
strlen: 6
str: %\n"s,
%\n"s, 
Word Scramble Start
strlen: 5
str: sr)t;
sr)t; 
Word Scramble Start
strlen: 1
} 
Word Scramble Start
strlen: 1
} 
Word Scramble Start
strlen: 3
int 
Word Scramble Start
strlen: 10
str: min(voida)
min(voida) 
Word Scramble Start
strlen: 1
{ 
Word Scramble Start
strlen: 18
str: pocessFile(stdinr,
pocessFile(stdinr, 
Word Scramble Start
strlen: 8
str: sdout)t;
sdout)t; 
Word Scramble Start
strlen: 6
str: rturen
rturen 
Word Scramble Start
strlen: 2
0; 
Word Scramble Start
strlen: 1
} End file processing
```

You probably need to deal with adding newlines after you get rid of most of the progress reporting prints.  Note that I removed a couple of dead (unused) variables and removed the `50` from the 'array size' to the `scramble()` function.  I set `MAXLINE` big enough, too.  And reading from standard input and writing to standard output is the simplest test harness for the code that I could think of.

You can reduce the amount of repetition in `processFile()` by another modication:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { MAXLINE = 4096 };

extern void processFile(FILE *ifp, FILE *ofp);
extern void scramble(char str[]);

void processFile(FILE *ifp, FILE *ofp)
{
    printf("Begin file processing\n");
    char istr[MAXLINE];
    char *token;
    char delimit[] = {" \t\r\n\v\f"};
    while (fgets(istr, MAXLINE, ifp) != NULL)
    {
        char *start = istr;
        while ((token = strtok(start, delimit)) != NULL)
        {
            scramble(token);
            fprintf(ofp, "%s ", token);
            start = NULL;
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    printf("End file processing\n");
}

void scramble(char str[])
{
    //printf("\nWord Scramble Start\n");
    int len = strlen(str);
    //printf("strlen: %d\n", len);
    if (len > 3)
    {
        int t = str[1];
        for (int k = 1; k < len - 2; k++)
            str[k] = str[k + 1];
        str[len - 2] = t;
        //printf("str: %s\n", str);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    processFile(stdin, stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

Instead of repeating the calls to `scramble()` and `fputs()`, it wraps it all in a loop, using `fprintf()` to do a single I/O operation.  It does leave trailing blanks; there are ways around that, too.

Comment: This worked, thanks, I guess the absence of a NULL check was causing the crashes after all. Not sure what I am getting downvoted for but thank you very much for taking the time to help me out.